# getting location in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation

I am trying to get the location from my device. This is the code:

```
public class Geolocation
{        
    private readonly LocationManager _locationManager;

    public Geolocation()
    {
        _locationManager = Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
    }

    public Task<double> GetLocation()
    {

        var provider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine }, true);
        var location = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location == null) return null;

        var result = location.Latitude;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I got this code from a book about xamarin. What I don't understand, why the majority of time I don't get a result from that? Few times it works, but I don't know why. For those wondering why am i not using James Montemagno's Geolocator plugin is because I can't. It requires something that can't be updated in my VS.

Comment: Can you add more detail as to why you can't use the GeoLocator plugin? Which dependencies are conflicting with which NuGet Packages?

Answer (score 1):

try to get coordination by dependency service. Read xamrin documentation 
[Get Current Device Location](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/)
There is a sample project in github [get_current_device_location](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location)

and still you want it to implement in xamarin.forms then see this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx5O9GfOnS4)

Answer (score 1):

```
_locationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse}, true);
```

This would give you the location faster, despite a lower accuracy of course. 
[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Location/Location/MainActivity.cs) is a comprehensive example of how the location should be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how to use the GeoLocator plugin from a Xamarin.Forms project.

This code snippet is taken from sample Xamarin.Forms app that uses the GeoLocator plugin with Xamarin.Forms and an MVVM architecture:

https://github.com/brminnick/GeolocatorSample

```
public class Geolocation
{ 
    string _latLongText, _latLongAccuracyText, _altitudeText, _altitudeAccuracyText;

    public Geolocation()
    {
        StartListeningForGeoloactionUpdates.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public string LatLongText
    {
        get => _latLongText;
        set => _latLongText = value;
    }

    public string LatLongAccuracyText
    {
        get => _latLongAccuracyText;
        set => _latLongAccuracyText = value;
    }

    public string AltitudeText
    {
        get => _altitudeText;
        set => _altitudeText = value;
    }

    public string AltitudeAccuracyText
    {
        get => _altitudeAccuracyText;
        set => _altitudeAccuracyText = value;
    }

    Task StartListeningForGeoloactionUpdates()
    {
        bool isGeolocationAvailable = CrossGeolocator.IsSupported
                                    && CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable
                                    && CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled;

        if (isGeolocationAvailable)
        {
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += HandlePositionChanged;
            return CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 10);
        }

        LatLongText = "Geolocation Unavailable";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void HandlePositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
        AltitudeAccuracyText = $"{ConvertDoubleToString(e.Position.AltitudeAccuracy, 0)}m";
        AltitudeText = $"{ConvertDoubleToString(e.Position.Altitude, 2)}m";
        LatLongAccuracyText = $"{ConvertDoubleToString(e.Position.Accuracy, 0)}m";
        LatLongText = $"{ConvertDoubleToString(e.Position.Latitude, 2)}, {ConvertDoubleToString(e.Position.Longitude, 2)}";

        string ConvertDoubleToString(double number, int decimalPlaces) => number.ToString($"F{decimalPlaces}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for your response my friend i already tried to used geolocator plugin but as i said in the question i can't use it because it needs api lvl25 and my vs can't download that api i don't know why

Comment: Use the Android SDK Manager to download the latest Android SDKs: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-sdk/

Comment: You shouldn’t be trying to reinvent the wheel; the GeoLocator Plugin does exactly what you need.

Comment: I actually did it but for an unknown reason it doesn't appear neither "compile using android version" list nor "target android version" list from project.droid properties, but i will try to reinstall it and i notice you if that solves the problem my friend

Comment: And yes i know that i don't need to be doing that but sometimes it needs to be done as a walkaround i guess

Comment: Installing the Android SDKs is the answer to your question. Building against the latest SDK (currently it’s v8.0) is critical for Android development.

Comment: I will try reinstalling api lvl25 and see what happens then

Comment: You should install Level 26, aka v8.0

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Geolocator plugin needs api level 25 means that the application will not work on older devices? Because the market is still full of Lollipop..

Comment: @Giox - You are confusing Android Build Target and Minimum Android Version. Your Android Build Target needs to be API Level 25 or higher to support the GeoLocator Plugin. You can lower the Minimum Android Version to allow older OSs to run your app; I recommend setting it to API Level 15.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick So even used on Lollipop, my app will work fine to get coordinates with the above code using Geolocator plugin?

Comment: Yes, as long as your Android Build Target is Level 25 or higher